# What happens in raid 1 when a disk becomes full?

Tags: hard-drive, raid

To start I'm pretty new to this stuff so I might be asking a question with an obvious answer here. But let's say I had two hard drives in raid 1: a 4tb drive and a 8tb drive. If the 4tb becomes full will the data only go the 8tb drive? Or if the drives are in raid 1 can it only be with a partition of the 8tb drive? Again I'm pretty new to this and I've never tinkered with raid before.

Comment: As you aren't familiar with RAID, you need to do more research on it and then apply it to what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

There are usually two choices, depending on what software or hardware you use to create the RAID array:

1. Either the RAID implementation won't accept different disk sizes in the first place,
2. Or the RAID implementation will accept the disk, but will only create a 4 TB mirrored array, leaving the remaining part of the larger disk unused.

If you get option 1, sometimes you *can* create matching partitions instead, which then again results in option 2. Usually this works with software-based RAID systems such as mdadm, less so with hardware RAID controllers.

In either case, disk mirroring systems are usually strict about ensuring that the specified number of copies is always satisfied – after all, redundancy is *kind of the whole point* of having a RAID1 array, so if it didn't even do this one job, it wouldn't be a very good product.

---

Note however that most traditional RAID systems *do not work with files*, so they don't even have the concept of a disk being "full" or "empty". They work with disk sectors, and a disk always has exactly the same amount of sectors regardless of how many files it holds.

(Some systems, such as Btrfs or Storage Spaces or LVM, are somewhat more flexible and can accept various disk combinations. Some of them indeed work at individual file level and will place the copies depending on space available, but they will nevertheless refuse to store data if they can't fulfill the redundancy requirements.)